# SAS: Add Conditional Variable To Existing Data Source

Tags: sas

First time writing SAS code. Trying to add a new numeric variable that has a conditional value based on another existing variable. This is what I have so far:

```
data dataset;
    set dataset;
    newnum = .;
    If oldnum >= 2;
    newnum = 1;
run;
```

I'm getting an error when I try to run this SAS Code node that is attached to the relevant data source item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no conditional statement in your code because you end your `IF` block with a semicolon. You need to move the newnum up to before the semicolon and add a `THEN`.

```
data dataset;
set dataset;
newnum = .;
If oldnum >= 2 then newnum = 1;
run;
```

As is, the line `If oldnum >=2` will filter your dataset and keep only records that have `oldnum>=2`. Then it will assign `newnum=1`. So it does do what you want, but the resulting dataset will only be a subset of the original data set.

Comment: thanks for the explanation! i will try this solution tonight and let you know. definitely seems like the right track!

Comment: I tried this, but got a system 1012 general error. just to clarify, the newnum is a new variable i want to insert into the dataset, but perhaps it isn't accepting it this way?

Comment: Hi Reeza, this is the exact code: `data EM_SAVE_TRAIN2;
 set EM_SAVE_TRAIN2;
 MED_DUM = .;
 If MEDV >= 25 THEN MED_DUM = 1;
run;`
log does say something interesting

Comment: `7702        set EM_SAVE_TRAIN2;
ERROR: File WORK.EM_SAVE_TRAIN2.DATA does not exist.
7703        MED_DUM = .;
7704        If MEDV >= 25 THEN MED_DUM = 1;
7705       run;

NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
WARNING: The data set WORK.EM_SAVE_TRAIN2 may be incomplete.  When this step was stopped there were 0 observations and 2 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds
      

7706       
7707       /*; *"; *'; */;`

Comment: the dataset is called EM_SAVE_TRAIN2, but in the log it is referencing it as WORK.EM_SAVE_TRAIN2. Is this the issue?

Comment: It says your data doesn't exist. Thats not an issue with the code provided. Verify your source data. Also, since your running this and creating a dataset with the same name (same data set in SET and DATA statement) if it fails you have to recreate the original dataset before you re-run.

Comment: You can try adding work but that should not be the issue, work is the default library

Comment: Hi Reeza, I'm trying multiple ways to add a valid source data. I've duplicated my original Data Source, and then tried using the name of that as the dataset. Am i missing something here?

Comment: Reeza, I found the right dataset, I had to create a new dataset to fill in the results. The code seems to have worked, but I can't seem to find the dataset anywhere. Would you know where I can add it into the Diagram?

Comment: Sadly no. I haven't worked with Eminer. If you post on communities.sas.com in Analytics/Data Mining forum ppl experienced in EM can help. Even the SAS developers pop in time to time.

Comment: If your working with EM you can do this through a recode task as well, you don't need code. I don't remember exact details of how though.

Comment: Hi Reeza, okay thanks for the help. Your input was very helpful